# How to make the background image fit page perfectly

Tags: html, css

The image was not perfectly fixing to the current page, How to make the background image fit page perfectly

```
 .background-image {
  background-image: url('camera.jpg'); 
  background-size: cover;
  display: block;
  height: 800px;
  left: -5px;
  top:-5px;
  bottom:-5px;
  right: -5px;
position: fixed;      
z-index: 1;
  margin:0px auto;
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  }
```

I tried this, but doesn't work along with blur

```
background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vj8skms4/

Comment: Please provide a jsiddle.

Comment: @Venkatesh : I can't find any difference if I remove the blur effect.

Comment: @Venkatesh which browser U are working?

Comment: @rJ7, using chrome v41

Comment: for me it's working as supposed - you can correct the negative (-5px) margins on left-right-top-bottom to 0, if that's what you want to do...

Comment: @maioman,I applied the -5px because after applying blur i 'm getting white blur borders, To remove these unnecessary white borders i applied -5px. I changed the -5px to 0px but still the image is not fit to the page and got white borders.

Comment: that's perfectly fine - I'll answer your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the background position property;
so , to have your image vertically center when it overflows horizontally , you should add:

```
 background: no-repeat center center fixed;
```

[here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maio/8wq132nd/1/)